When were Compatibilist and Incompatibilist Free Will Defined?
I have seen several incidents where people arguing over free will would accuse each other redefining the concept of free will in order to win an argument. I may have also been at some point convinced that this was what happened with compatibilists, but currently am not so confident about the matter, and would like to know the historical basis or lack thereof for this belief.
Thus the question: when libertarians accuse compatibilists of redefining free will, is it actually the case? Does the compatibilist definition of free will postdate the incompatibilist / libertarian / causality-defying / indeterministic but non-stochastic definition of what free will is? All this these questions should be resolved by knowing the answer to the matter of when were the two definitions of free will first established (e.g. published or attested in someone else's philosophical speeches)?

@vickymoIokh I recommend the online encyclopedy  https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/compatibilism/

Libertarians (Aristotle, Epicurus) and compatibilists (Chrysippus) go back to ancient Greece, at least, albeit without the names, see SEP. Who was "first" to "define" is moot anyway, the real question is, presumably, which concept of free will better matches pre-existing folk intuitions. Modern field studies showed that the folk have both compatibilist and libertarian intuitions, and which come up is sensitive to how the issue is formulated and framed.

Stoics, & Aquinas, were Compatibilists. Free will gained special currency as an idea in theodicy, in addressing the Problem of Evil specifically in Christianity, & reconciling personal accountability with predestination. It's noteworthy that other Abrahamic faiths, never mind Indian & Chinese thinkers, just don't see an issue.
